# Complex File parsing in spark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark with scala 2.4

My source data looks like as given below.

```
Salesperson_21: Customer_575,Customer_2703,Customer_2682,Customer_2615
Salesperson_11: Customer_454,Customer_158,Customer_1859,Customer_2605
Salesperson_10: Customer_1760,Customer_613,Customer_3008,Customer_1265
Salesperson_4: Customer_1545,Customer_1312,Customer_861,Customer_2178
```

Code used to flat the file.

```
val SalespersontextDF = spark.read.text("D:/prints/sales.txt")
val stringCol = SalespersontextDF.columns.map(c => s"'$c', cast(`$c` as string)").mkString(", ")
    val processedDF = SalespersontextDF.selectExpr(s"stack(${df1.columns.length}, $stringCol) as (Salesperson, Customer)")
```

[image]

Unfortunately it is not populating salesperson in correct field , instead of salesperson number it is populating hardcoded value as "value". and salesperson number shift to another field.

Appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below approach might solve your problem,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val SalespersontextDF = spark.read.text("/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/data/sales.txt")

val stringCol = SalespersontextDF.columns.map(c => s"'$c', cast(`$c` as string)").mkString(", ")

val processedDF = SalespersontextDF.selectExpr(s"stack(${SalespersontextDF.columns.length}, $stringCol) as (Salesperson, Customer)")

processedDF.show(false)
/*
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Salesperson|Customer                                                              |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value      |Salesperson_21: Customer_575,Customer_2703,Customer_2682,Customer_2615|
|value      |Salesperson_11: Customer_454,Customer_158,Customer_1859,Customer_2605 |
|value      |Salesperson_10: Customer_1760,Customer_613,Customer_3008,Customer_1265|
|value      |Salesperson_4: Customer_1545,Customer_1312,Customer_861,Customer_2178 |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
*/

processedDF.withColumn("Salesperson", split($"Customer", ":").getItem(0)).withColumn("Customer", split($"Customer", ":").getItem(1)).show(false)
/*
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|Salesperson   |Customer                                               |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|Salesperson_21| Customer_575,Customer_2703,Customer_2682,Customer_2615|
|Salesperson_11| Customer_454,Customer_158,Customer_1859,Customer_2605 |
|Salesperson_10| Customer_1760,Customer_613,Customer_3008,Customer_1265|
|Salesperson_4 | Customer_1545,Customer_1312,Customer_861,Customer_2178|
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much........ but only 1 problem, when i trying to join with other csv file and pivot.... columns value are shifting. please allow me to edit question and add error snapshot.

Comment: please accept myself or @Someshwar Kale answer and raise a new question and update us.

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```scala
spark.read
        .schema("Salesperson STRING, Customer STRING")
      .option("sep", ":")
      .csv("D:/prints/sales.txt")
```